# Confusing result when pattern matching a BlankSequence (__) to a list, then calling unary function on the list

Tags: pattern-matching, rule, sequence

The following makes sense to me:

```
In[1] = f[a, b] /. f[x__] -> x
Out[1] = Sequence[a, b]

In[2] = f[a, b] /. f[x__] -> {x}
Out[2] = {a, b}
```

However, the following don't make sense:

```
In[3] = f[a, b] /. f[x__] -> Length[{x}]
Out[3] = 1

In[4] = f[a, b] /. f[x__] -> Total[{x}]
Out[4] = Sequence[a,b]
```

I was expecting the following: `Out[3] = 2` and `Out[4] = a + b`, especially considering the value of `Out[2]`. Am I missing something here? Is there some subtle nuance of `BlankSequence` that I have missed?

I'm using Mathematica desktop 13.2.1.0 on Debian 11.

Comment: `f[a, b] /. f[x__] :> Length[{x}]` would give `2`.

Comment: I think you post the wrong sample for `In[4]`?

Comment: fixed, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

It's because `->` evaluates the right hand side of the rule **eagerly** when the rule is defined, not when it's later applied. In the case of `In[3]`, we have

```
In[3] = f[a, b] /. f[x__] -> Length[{x}]
```

Before applying the rule, the RHS `Length[{x}]` is evaluated to 1. Then we replace `x` with `Sequence[a,b]` in the expression 1, which still is just 1.

Similarly, in `In[4]`, the expression `Total[{x}]` is first evaluated to just `x`, and then after replacement, we get `Sequence[a,b]`.